# shell script to append files in the column wise fashion

Tags: shell

I have tried to append two files containing following data

**1st file:**

```
123456789
987654321
000000000
```

**2nd file:**

```
abcdefghij
1111111111
3333333333
```

**Required file:**

```
123456789abcdefghij
9876543211111111111
0000000003333333333
```

What I mean to say is that I want to merge two files column wise. Is there any shell script for that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `paste` for this:

```
$ paste f1 f2
123456789       abcdefghij
987654321       1111111111
000000000       3333333333
```

And then remove the tab with `tr`:

```
$ paste f1 f2 | tr -d '\t'
123456789abcdefghij
9876543211111111111
0000000003333333333
```

---

Or even shorter ([thanks mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017317/shell-script-to-append-files-in-the-column-wise-fashion/22017362?noredirect=1#comment33374254_22017362)!), use `\0` as delimiter in between files, which means be printed together:

```
$ paste -d'\0' f1 f2
123456789abcdefghij
9876543211111111111
0000000003333333333
```

Comment: Hi friend how you people have got such a talent awesome answer

Comment: Haha I happen to be here for some months and have learnt from the gurus!

Comment: +1; if you use `paste -d'\0' f1 f2`, you can skip the `tr` step (works with at least the GNU and OSX versions).

Comment: Hi dude i am continuously trying to press that check but it is saying after 10min only u can check that ..

Comment: Ok good point @mklement0 , I tried to use `-d ''` and did not work to me. I will update showing it, many thanks!

Comment: @user3351610 no problem , it is because you cannot accept within the first 15 minutes. In a couple of minutes you should be able :)

Comment: Hey guys i also want to vote for mklement0's comment.. how can i do that

Comment: @Vinodkumar if you move your mouse to the left side of the comment you will see an arrow. If you press, it will upvote the comment. In general, you can see your privileges in --> http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: Errr @Vinodkumar what happened?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `pr` core utility and do:

```
pr -mJtS'' f1 f2
```

```
$ cat f1
123456789
987654321
000000000
```

```
$ cat f2
abcdefghij
1111111111
3333333333
```

```
$ pr -mJtS'' f1 f2
123456789abcdefghij
9876543211111111111
0000000003333333333
```

Comment: Another little known utility, `pr`!